# Are things powered by the amount of joules (energy) in a coloumb or by the amount of joules (energy) flowing every second?

Tags: voltage

My question is in the title, ***Are components powered by Volts or Joules?***

I believe it is joules/coloumb, right?

Because, if things are powered by Joules/Second then that would mean that the current affects how many Joules are getting supplied and things like that.

So my assumption is that things are powered by Voltage (joules/coloumb), and Joules/second (amps * voltage) or **Watts** are the measurement of that power, is that correct?

Because if things use the energy from the joules/second then that means that both amps and voltage should play a part. For example, if I had 2A and 3V then that is 6 joules/second if only that voltage is supply things than the component would take advantage of the joules in each coloumb not the amount of joules coming through every second.

Alright read my answer, this should clear everything up, I realized how I had a misunderstanding of concept. The answer clears up the misunderstanding.

Comment: neither is right. Your arguments demonstrate a lacking understanding of what a Joule is, what a Volt is, what a Watt is, and what they measure and how these physical entities relate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am a beginner, could you please tell me more?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know that voltage measures joules/coloumb and watts measuere joules per second

Comment: you should think about what entity these units measure – for example, Joule is a measure of *energy*. You're mixing up unit of measurement and described physical property.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So... volts don’t measure how many joules of _energy_ are in every coulomb and don’t show how much _energy_ is being supplied to a component and watts aren’t joules a second and don’t measure the energy consumed

Comment: again, try to mentally make a difference between a *unit of measurement* (e.g. Joule), and the thing described by it (e.g. energy). What you said in your last comment is mostly right, but confusing / misleading.

Comment: Translate your title ("things powered by *Volts* or *Joules*") to that more sensible question: "are things powered by *voltage* or *energy*?" and you'll notice that they are neither. They are powered by *power*.

Comment: But power is watts which is joules a second which is amps times voltage?

Comment: Could you please explain rather than encourage to think, I am newbie and am having trouble understanding...

Comment: @BeastCoder2  Joules is energy, which is the integral of watts (as a function of time) over time. You worry about Joules when are concerned about the total energy in a battery or a capacitor. You worry about Watts when you are concerned about the ability to deliver a certain number of Joules in a certain time period.

Comment: *But power is watts which is joules a second which is amps times voltage?*: **No,** it's not. Power is *measured* in watts. Really. I won't repeat for a fourth time: make a difference between unit of measurement and described entity. This is middle school physics level stuff.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay. So I think I have made the difference.... I am really sorry for not understanding completely.... but is the difference that voltage and joules dont power anything they just measure how much power is flowing. So if that is the case, what does power it?

Comment: no, that's not the point (nor true). Sorry, I'll stop responding now. Please read wikipedia on [*Units of Measurement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measurement) and try to understand what the difference between a unit and the described quantity is. I've repeated myself enough.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please dont, I know that the measurement _clearly_ isn’t supplying the energy it is measuring it. I am asking which measurement is used to represent how much charge is used to energize, say an LED. Now do you understand? I know that the measurement, _a representation_ cant power something, it is a _representation_

Comment: no. It's a unit. I give up.

Comment: I reverted your last edit. You removed the content of the question.  I put it back for context in case someone lands here in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[Voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage) electric potential difference, electric pressure or electric tension is the difference in electric potential between two points.

[Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) is the rate of flow of electric charge past a point or region.

[Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) (electric) is the rate, per unit time, at which electrical energy is transferred by an electric circuit. The SI unit of power is the watt, one joule per second.

[Electrical energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_energy) is energy derived from electric potential energy or kinetic energy. When used loosely, "electrical energy" refers to energy that has been converted from electric potential energy. This energy is supplied by the combination of electric current and electric potential that is delivered by an electrical circuit (e.g., provided by an electric power utility). At the point that this electric potential energy has been converted to another type of energy, it ceases to be electric potential energy. Thus, all electrical energy is potential energy before it is delivered to the end-use. Once converted from potential energy, electrical energy can always be called another type of energy (heat, light, motion, etc.).

---

From the comments:

> ... on an LED when it says that its forward voltage is 2 V because it needs 2 volts, is it using the joules (measure of energy) ...

No. This may help:

[image]

*Figure 1. The diode / check valve analogy.*

LEDs are diodes (that emit light). Diodes are electrical non-return valves. (This is due to their rectification properties and that they behave like a certain type of valve in a water system.)

The diode check-valve analogy.

If you look at the check-valve in the figure above, it should be clear that the spring normally keeps the ball in position and prevents back-flow. When “forward-biased” the ball shut-off can be moved against the spring but it will take some initial pressure to move the ball. This results in a pressure drop across the valve: the pressure downstream will be less than the inlet pressure.

In a similar manner the PN junction causes a voltage drop. For silicon it is about 0.7 V. For LEDs it is higher and depends on the current.

It should be clear by now that no flow will occur in the check valve until the pressure rises enough to cause current to flow. Similarly in the diode (or LED) no current will flow until the voltage rises enough to forward bias the diode. There's a little more in my linked article.

Comment: oh.. okay! So, I have one more question, on an LED when it says that its forward voltage is 2V because it needs 2 volts, is it using the joules (measure of energy), or I could say energy, per second. Or, is it using the amount of joules, again I could say energy, per each coulomb

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I updated my question, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Many components (ICs, circuit boards) are designed to have a certain voltage connected  between its supply voltage pins. If the user connects nothing or wrong voltage, the component does nothing or gets broken.

Many 2 terminal components such as resistors, capacitors, inductors, diodes can accept various voltages connected to their terminals (hopefully you have noticed that voltage always is something between 2 separate points in a component or circuit). The function of those parts is to let some certain current go through the part. The law how the current depends on the voltage and time is what the component does. Resistors obey Ohm's law, diodes are designed to allow more current to one direction than to the other with as high voltage. Capacitors and inductors have also time in their laws which are differential equations (=rules how fast things change)

Then there are components which have more than 2 terminals. Their working is complex. Many of them, for ex. transistors are designed to allow one voltage control the current through the part via other terminals. A relay is also for this purpose.

If one builds a circuit, all currents and voltages in the circuit obey the laws of the components and general circuit laws. Nothing else is possible. Designing a circuit isn't possible before one is able to say how the currents and voltages should vary along the time and how they should depend on each other.

Your question "Which powers a component - Volts or Joules?" Answer: None of them. Volts  and Joules are measuring units for common physical quantities. You must assemble a component to a circuit to make it to do something else than exist. Many components do nothing if in the circuit there's no parts which generate some voltage or have it as stored charge. In that sense you can sing a song or utter a poem which says "Voltage powers components", but that's poetry, not science.

Your question stops to be nonsense as soon as you can tell the meaning of the term A powers B  ie. say the logic equation which is true exactly when object B is powered by A and is false when B isn't powered at all or something else than A does the powering.

Comment: So the joules/coloumb powers the components or no, is that the same thing?

Comment: @BeastCoder2 this talks is useless until we have a common exact definition for "A powers B". The definition should not introduce new mathematically undefined terms.

Answer (score 0):

It's Energy that makes things work, aka powers things.

In investigative journalism, you follow the money. In physics, you follow the energy. You can't go wrong in physics if you consider the energy first, and then see what else shakes out.

Take a battery-powered gizmo. The battery provides energy to the circuit. The circuit operates. No energy from the battery, no gizmo operation.

Energy is measured in units of Joules. With mechanical energy, one joule is the energy required to lift a 100g apple 1m from the floor to a table-top. One joule is what's released when it falls the same distance.

Power is the rate at which energy is transferred. One watt is one joule per second. You would be working on the apple at one watt lifting it from floor to table in one second. You would be working at 10 watts if you did it in 100mS.

Energy is generally the product of two quantities, often a pressure-like thing, and a distance-like thing. Mechanical energy is force times distance, power is force times speed. Electrical energy is volts times coulombs, power is volts times current. Rotational energy is torque times angle, power is torque times angular velocity.

Comment: Look at my edit (to the question), do I understand it, or, what do you think...

Comment: @BeastCoder2 You are much, much less wrong. While that's a significant improvement, I'd be doing you a disservice if I said it was right. 'More amps in the negative terminal' is totally wrong, I can't even imagine where you're coming from to frame a counter-argument, so if you can, just unthink that.

Comment: whoops... meant to have you look at my updated answer, is it correct?

Comment: @BeastCoder2 A coulomb is one ampere.second, not one amp. A 9v battery delivers 9 joules for every coulomb of charge that passes out of one terminal and back into the other. Energy is needed to power a circuit, and the unit of energy is the Joule. Whether voltage is what moves a circuit along ... sort of, not a good phrase. Most people start out learning that voltage makes a current flow. But when we learn some more, we realise that even in something simple like a resistor, voltage and current happen at the same time, one doesn't cause the other, or they both cause each other.